# Cross the elements in a matrix

Tags: open-source, math

I have a demo matrix

```
0 0 0 0
7 2 0 3
9 5 0 4
```

What I want is to remove the rows or columns that have all 0 elements, so the expected result will be:

```
7 2 3
9 5 4
```

For the demo purpose, I want to use dash lines to mark the rows or columns which are needed to be processed.
Let's see the picture.

[image: demo]

What software can do it?

Comment: Which input format would you like to have? Does a simple textual input (as the one in your question) suffice?

Comment: The OP said in a comment on a now deleted answer that he is looking for an image editing software. @Love Do you know LaTeX? See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40044/38074) for an example of what it can do. Depending on your settings, it can produce a PDF.